# Indented $http calls with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, http

I am trying to make multiple `$http` calls on an API interface to update my model.
Let me explain. I want to save a new object to my database, and once that object has been saved, I would like to get that object back and perform another `$http` call that updates another object. Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
var departmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username     : { type:String,unique:true,required:true},
    email        : { type:String,unique:true,required:true},
    name         : { type:String, default:"", unique:true,required:true},
    stations     : { 
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], 
        ref: 'Station' 
    }
})

// Method that Pushes a Station to the department
departmentSchema.methods.pushStation = function(station) {
    var department = this;
    department.stations.push(station)
};
```

**API Route**

```
router.put('/departments/:dep_id/stations/:stat_id', function(req, res, next) {
    Station.findOne({_id: req.params.stat_id}, function(err, data1){
       if (err) { return next(err); }

       var station = data1; 
        Department.findOne({_id: req.params.dep_id}, function(err, data2){
            if (err) { return next(err); }

            var department = data2;
            department.pushStation(station)
            res.json({success:true, department:department});
        });
    });
});
```

**Angularjs $http indented Calls**

```
$scope.addNewStation = function(station){
    $http.post('/api/stations/', station)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        $scope.station = data.station;
        $http.put('/api/departments/' + $scope.department._id + '/stations/' + $scope.station._id, $scope.station)
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        bootbox.alert("Station Created Successfully");

    },function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

I should point out that I have `$scope.department` in my URL, and this is because I get that data from a previous call, and I didn't want to crowd this section with unnecessary code.
So the problem is that when I execute `$scope.addNewStation(...)`, I am able to add the new Station successfully, the bootbox alert appears, the first `console.log(data)` is displayed, but then I get an error on the console stating: `TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined` and the second `console.log(data)` doesn't show up.
Please tell me what I a doing wrong here. I really need help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but. Can't see scope.department._id  where is setted

Comment: Instead of nesting the calls, why not use a "waterfall"?
[Here's a link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall)

Comment: Hey @federicoscamuzzi, like I explained above, $scope.department is an object that has been returned from a previous call. And that object contains $scope.department._id. So just assume that it's there.

Comment: Hey @DavidStenstrøm can you give me an example of what you are talking about? Thanks.

Comment: `Cannot read property '_id' of undefined` So you have not `$scope.department` or `$scope.station` defined

Comment: @AllJs Can you `console.log($scope.department)` and `console.log($scope.station)` before the second $http call and post the results here? The error you're getting indicates one of those is undefined, so you should check which one it is so you can continue debugging with more information

Comment: @Fissio the `console.log($scope.station)` returns `undefined` in my case, which is weird to me. `console.log($scope.department)` returns the full object as expected.

Comment: @AllJs What does the `console.log(data)` show then? It probably doesn't have a `station` attribute... EDIT: Actually, the `$http.post` returns a response object, you should be doing `$scope.station = data.data.station`

Comment: @Fissio. You were right. I should have done `$scope.station = data.data.station`. I tested it and it worked. Please post a definite answer so that I can award you the correct answer on this one. Thanks for your help here man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object in the `.then()` callback is a response object, which includes status, data and other attributes. You should do something along the following:

```
$http.post('/api/stations/', station)
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.station = response.data.station;
})
```

Comment: Yes Fissio. your suggestion answered my question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using angular promise, also check whether the scope variables station and department are correctly initialized.

```
var promise = $http.post('/api/stations/', station);

promise.then(
  function(data) {
     $scope.station = data.station;
        console.log($scope.station, $scope.department);
        $http.put('/api/departments/' + $scope.department._id + '/stations/' + $scope.station._id, $scope.station)
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an [async waterfall.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall)

Here's an example (on the backend):

```
var waterfall = require('async-waterfall');
waterfall([
    function(callback){
        callback(null, 'param1');//the first parameter is the error - if there is one
    },
    function(param2, callback){
        callback(null, 'param2');
    }
], function(err, result){
    // if no errors send response back to angular
})
```

This way you can do without the nested calls. For better examples, see the link I provided.